# Elastic Search java (spring) issue at indexing

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have integrated elastic-search 1.7.1 with spring application.I have a cron job which update the index of elasticsearch on every run. 
I have followed various example codes available on github to make it work.First I have Autowired ElasticSearchOperations for indexing purpose:

```
@Autowired
private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;
```

Then inside loop indexing is perform in following manner

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    CategoryProductSearch search = new CategoryProductSearch();
    // set data to fields
    System.out.println("BEFORE SAVING DATA");
    IndexQuery indexQuery =new      

    IndexQueryBuilder().withId(search.getId()).withObject(search).build();
    //indexQuery.setId(search.getId());
    //indexQuery.setObject(search);
    //elasticsearchOperations.createIndex(CategoryProductSearch.class);
    elasticsearchOperations.putMapping(CategoryProductSearch.class);
    elasticsearchOperations.index(indexQuery);
    elasticsearchOperations.refresh(CategoryProductSearch.class,true);

    System.out.println("SAVING DATA");
 }
```

When i run it for first time it works as expected. I have renamed cluster to "mycluster" in elasticsearch.yml inside config folder. After first run i can see the folder created. Indexing and searching(Implemented in another file) works perfectly. But sometimes the code get stuck at below mentioned line and shows continuous warning [Chase Stein] node null not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...

```
 elasticsearchOperations.putMapping(CategoryProductSearch.class);
```

Then after some time it throws NoNodeAvailableException. I have read about this issue and it says there might not be enough disk space for elastic-search to index data. 
I am new to spring and have tried elastic-search for the first time. Is this a disk space issue or something wrong in a way i am indexing data? 
Also if i manually delete "mycluster" folder from /data directory and restart application it works fine again.!

I have everything set up on my local PC. Whenever i restart elasticsearch service this issue comes in.

Stack trace for the exception is:

```
  org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [mycluster][0]       

  Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned to a known node. Timeout:    

  [1m], request: index {[mycluster][categoryproductsearch][1], 

  source[{// Source string }]
at 
  org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication
  .TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase
  .retryBecauseUnavailable
  (TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:655)
at 
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication
  .TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun
  (TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:362)
at 

  org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run
  (AbstractRunnable.java:36)
at 
   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.
   TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase$3.onTimeout
   (TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:515)
at  

 org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener
 .onTimeout
 (ClusterStateObserver.java:231)
at    
     org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.
    InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run
    (InternalClusterService.java:560)
at 
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
     (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at 
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
     (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at 
      java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you checked the disk space usage on your harddisk? How big is your `/data` folder before deleting it?

Comment: yes i checked the disk space. It varies between 10-20% and /data directory is around 65 kb. That's why i doubt the way i am indexing.

Comment: One thing is certain, though, you only need to call `putMapping` once outside the for-loop. Second, I'm not sure what exactly you're indexing because `CategoryProductSearch` seems empty or is this done where you have commented `//set data to fields`?

Comment: yes the fields are being set in the commented part. I skipped it in question. I will putMapping outside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i took this code from [generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer)

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> void reindexForClass(Class<T> entityClass, JpaRepository<T, Long> jpaRepository,
                                                      ElasticsearchRepository<T, Long> elasticsearchRepository) {
    elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(entityClass);
    try {
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(entityClass);
    } catch (IndexAlreadyExistsException e) {
        // Do nothing. Index was already concurrently recreated by some other service.
    }
    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(entityClass);
    if (jpaRepository.count() > 0) {
        try {
            Method m = jpaRepository.getClass().getMethod("findAllWithEagerRelationships");
            elasticsearchRepository.save((List<T>) m.invoke(jpaRepository));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            elasticsearchRepository.save(jpaRepository.findAll());
        }
    }
    log.info("Elasticsearch: Indexed all rows for " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
}
```

As you can see index is first deleted then created again an mapping is put, i think that your order is wrong and that it results in some broken shards. You can access Elastic Rest API on localhost:9200 and try a get request /_cat/indices to see your indexes.